# How to display multiple UIImageViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uiimageview

I have 5 images I would like to display on the view randomly. My image names are as follows: image-0, image-1, image-2, image-3, image-4.

What I need is I want to display each image, but the problem is when I write the code to display a second, it stacks on top of the first image. Here is my code to display one of my images:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
int xValue = arc4random() % 320;
int yValue = arc4random() % 480;
image.center = CGPointMake(xValue, yValue);


{UIImageView *imgFive = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image-5.png"]];
[self.view addSubview:imgFive];
    imgFive.center = CGPointMake(xValue, yValue);}
```

But if I add the same code but instead of "image-5.png" I use the other file names to try and display them, they stack on top of eachother. My images are circles, each varying size. So when I try and display all 5 I can see my circles have stacked on top of eachother from smallest to largest.

What do I need to do to separate these images from eachother? Do I need to put these images in an array and then loop through the array to display them how I would like?

Any help is appreciated, I am very new to coding so a simple explanation would be helpful in explaining why your code works.

Thanks again!

Comment: Did you solve your problem? Please mark the correct answer to mark this post as answered. And have a look at your code, this is not a valid syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Considering your requirement, and the general structure names provided to your images, i guess you need to just loop your logic .

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {

    float xpos = arc4random() %320 ;
    float ypos = arc4random() %480 ;

    UIImage *image = 
     [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image-%d.png",i]] ;

    UIImageView *imageView = 
     [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];

    imageView.center=CGPointMake(xpos, ypos);
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];          
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't change the xValue and yValue of each UIImageView, their centers will be aligned and will appear stacked on top of each other.

Comment: How do I change the xValue and yValue? I thought the arc4random set it randomly?

Comment: `yourImageView.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)`

Answer (score 0):

You assign the `xValue` and `yValue` only once at the start of the method body, so assigning the same `(x,y)` coordinates to all circles will naturally make them stack on top of one another (on the `z` axis of course). You need to have different values for `xValue` and `yValue` each time you assign the center property on any one circle and, yes, looping is a good strategy for that.

A good start would be to use a `for` loop construct to iterate an `int` variable from 0 to 4, and in each iteration:

1. assigning new random values to both `xValue` and `yValue`
2. setting the `center` property accordingly of one of your imageviews accordingly
3. adding it as a subview of `self.view`

   ```
   - (void) viewDidLoad {

       int xValue, yValue;
       NSString *imageName;
       UIImageView *image;
       for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
           imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image-%d.png", i];
           image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];
           xValue = arc4random() % 320;
           yValue = arc4random() % 480;
           image.center = CGPointMake(xValue, yValue);
           [self.view addSubview:image];
       }

   }
   ```

Comment: Im a little confused on what you mean by having different values for xValue and yValue? I thought the arc4random () gave them random numbers? How do I go about assigning new values then? xValue2 and yValue2?

Comment: There, I included some example code. The `arc4random()` call needs to be done every time you want to assign the center property.

Answer (score 0):

Your images are stacking because when you add an image via the method `addSubview`, it will stay until you remove the image with the method call `removeFromSuperview`. However, let's make this process a bit more robust.

First, in your Storyboard file, drag a UIImageView to your view. Set it's dimensions to your likieng. Then pressing on the Assistant Editor (the little tuxedo icon in the upper right hand side), it *should* open the corresponding `.h` file of the view controller you are editing. Take the UIImageView you have on your view, hold CTRL and drag over to your `.h` file [image], give it a name like `imageToDisplay`

When you let go you should see code appear in your `.h` file that reads:
`@property (weak, nonatamoic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageToDisplay;`
[image]

Add one more property, this time a NSArray, and this time you don't need Storyboard:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *imageArray;
```

Now back in you `.m` file, in your `viewDidLoad` method, let's make an array of `UIImage`s:

```
UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image-1.png"];
UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image-2.png"];
UIImage *image3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image-3.png"];
UIImage *image4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image-4.png"];
UIImage *image5 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image-5.png"];

_imageArray = @[image1, image2, image3, image4, image5];
```

Now that we have our 5 images in our array, we can now pick a random image from the array and assign it to our `UIImageView` property which is wired up to our view. 
Also, let's make our `_imageToDisplay alpha` property equal 0.0 so that we can have more digretion with what image is displayed, and how it is displayed:

```
//Still in viewDidLoad
_imageToDisplay.alpha = 0.0;
```

We can also do fun things like animations and other things as such. Let's make a method to make this easy:

```
-(void)displayImageRandomlyOnView {

//First, let's pick a random image to display. We will do this by generating a random number based from the count of our imageArray

NSUInteger randomIndex = arc4random_uniform([_imageArray count]);

//Now let's pick the random image with the objectAtIndex method for NSArray's. We will assign this image to our _imageToDisplay's .image property.

_imageToDisplay.image = [_imageArray objectAtIndex:randomIndex];

//Now using your original code, we can randomly define the frame of our _imageToDisplay
int xValue = arc4random() % 320;
int yValue = arc4random() % 480;

_imageToDisplay.frame = CGRectMake(xValue, yValue, CGRectGetWidth(_imageToDisplay.frame), CGRectGetHeight(_imageToDisplay.frame));

//Now if you remember, our imageToDisplay 's value is still 0.0, so let's animate it to show our randomly chosen image and location.

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^ {
        _imageToDisplay.alpha = 1.0;
    }];
}
```

This is how the code should appear in your `.h` file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageToDisplay;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *imageArray;
@end
```

This is how all the code should appear in your `.m` file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image-1.png"];
    UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image-2.png"];
    UIImage *image3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image-3.png"];
    UIImage *image4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image-4.png"];
    UIImage *image5 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image-5.png"];

    _imageArray = @[image1, image2, image3, image4, image5];
    _imageToDisplay.alpha = 0.0;
}

-(void)displayImageRandomlyOnView {

    //First, let's pick a random image to display. We will do this by generating a random number based from the count of our imageArray

    NSUInteger randomIndex = arc4random_uniform([_imageArray count]);

    //Now let's pick the random image with the objectAtIndex method for NSArray's. We will assign this image to our _imageToDisplay's .image property.

    _imageToDisplay.image = [_imageArray objectAtIndex:randomIndex];

    //Now using your original code, we can randomly define the frame of our _imageToDisplay
    int xValue = arc4random() % 320;
    int yValue = arc4random() % 480;

    _imageToDisplay.frame = CGRectMake(xValue, yValue, CGRectGetWidth(_imageToDisplay.frame), CGRectGetHeight(_imageToDisplay.frame));

    //Now if you remember, our imageToDisplay 's value is still 0.0, so let's animate it to show our randomly chosen image and location.

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^ {
        _imageToDisplay.alpha = 1.0;
    }];
}
```

Now every time you run this method, you will have a randomly selected image be displayed, along with a random position. I would play with your random values to make sure that the image will stay in bounds of your view.

In addition, as a challenge, try to hook up this method to a `UIButton` in your view, and make it that every time you press the button, the method we made `-(void)displayImageRandomlyOnView` gets called and changes your image.

Let me know if you need any more clarification!

Comment: I used the code posted by Benny Dalby and got all of the images to display and each time I opened the screen the positions changed! Then I soon realized I need it to randomly pick images to display and read your post. So I used all of your code, and now when I get to the screen its blank. I am not sure why the images are not being displayed on the view. Also, just curious if you can help with this too: each of my images will have a value. image-5=5, image-4=4 and so on. How would I pick images randomly and display them all until those values above equal 50? Thanks again for any advice

Answer (score 0):

To specifically answer what you are asking (although the other answers do give you a lot of better ways to organize your code):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
float xValue = arc4random() % 320;
float yValue = arc4random() % 480;

UIImageView *imgOne = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image-1.png"]];
imgOne.center = CGPointMake(xValue, yValue);
[self.view addSubview:imgOne];

// re-randomize the location
xValue = arc4random() % 320;
yValue = arc4random() % 480;

UIImageView *imgTwo = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image-2.png"]];
imgTwo.center = CGPointMake(xValue, yValue);
[self.view addSubview:imgTwo];
}
```

You need to make sure you generate new values for xValue and yValue each time you create a new image.

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSDictionary *picturesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"PhotesArray" ofType:@"plist"]];
NSArray *imageNames = [picturesDictionary objectForKey:@"Photos"];
NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i=0; i<[imageNames count]; i++) {
    [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[imageNames objectAtIndex:i]]];
}
//Normal animation
self.dataImageView.animationImages = images;
self.dataImageView.animationDuration = 5.0;
[self.dataImageView startAnimating];
```

Comment: Would you please explain this`